# Retrieve the insert user data from UItextField in Table View

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I create UITableView and add textfields to the content of cell to allow the user to enter his data and when the user end editing the text field I want to save the insert data in text field, but the problem is the `UITextField` retrieve null.

At `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I added

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];            
    }

     TextField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80,45)];
     TextField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(83, 0, 70,45)];
     TextField3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(156, 0, 70,45)];
     [TextField1 setDelegate:self];
     [TextField2 setDelegate:self];
     [TextField3 setDelegate:self];
     TextField1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
     TextField1.enabled=YES;
     TextField2.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
     TextField2.enabled=YES;
     TextField3.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
     TextField3.enabled=YES;
     [cell.contentView addSubview:TextField1];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:TextField2];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:TextField3];

     return cell;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSString*VisitDateStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",TextField1.text];
    NSLog(@"%@",VisitDateStr);
}
```

The result (null).
How I can retrieve the user details which insert on textfield at the tableview?

Thanks, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code :

```
-(void)textChanged:(UITextField *)textField

{
    NSString*VisitDateStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text];
}
```

Use this delegate method:

Set delegate to self in `cellforRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Comment: Thank you Samkit Jain, I retrieve null.

Comment: Are you getting textField also as nil ?

Comment: Yes its null I print the result using     NSLog(@"%@",TextField1.text);
the result  (null)

Comment: Try my improved answer

Comment: I used your answer but the same result its (null).

Comment: Or you just want data to be added for that time only...and once you are editig your text, data is getting flushed out on table reload ?

Comment: Then, you need to use the nsuserdefaults etc...but for your issue you can tag you textFields and using tag you can find which is pressed and then save the data

Comment: Yes, I use tag for textfield TextField1.tag = 1; and so on.. how I can find which textfield is pressed? I put NSLog to check tag in textFieldDidEndEditing..but how I can benefited from this info?

Comment: try printing textField.tag

Comment: I get the textfield tag, but the UITextfield text is null for all.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try out this 


    -(void)textChanged:(UITextField *)textField

    {
        NSString*VisitDateStr=[[NSString alloc]init];
        VisitDateStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",TextField1.text];
    }


or
-(void)textChanged:(UITextField *)textField

    {
        NSString*VisitDateStr=[[NSString alloc]init];
        VisitDateStr=TextField1.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",VisitDateStr);
    }
```